# How to create data structures using value types?

Tags: oop, data-structures, linked-list, value-type

Data Structures like double linked list, trees and Graph ..etc needs reference type nodes to be implemented. usually implemented with classes and objects

is there is a way to use value types like structs in implementing those?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? In what language?

Comment: I used swift which have both reference and value types, I was thinking about functional programming, and its emphasis on value types data structures, I was wondering about its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Liked list implementation using `struct`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct Node { 
    int data; 
    struct Node* next; 
}; 

// Program to create a simple linked 
// list with 3 nodes 
int main() 
{ 
    struct Node* head = NULL; 
    struct Node* second = NULL; 
    struct Node* third = NULL; 

    // allocate 3 nodes in the heap 
    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    head->data = 1; // assign data in first node 
    head->next = second; // Link first node with 

    // the second node 
    // assign data to second node 
    second->data = 2; 

    // Link second node with the third node 
    second->next = third; 

    return 0; 
}
```